# Report lab Bar code Generation store file to S3?

Tags: python, python-3.6, boto3, reportlab, django-1.11

I am following this (https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Barcodes) tutorial to handle bar code generation of my site

```
MyBarcodeDrawing("HELLO WORLD").save(formats=['gif','pdf'],outDir='.',fnRoot='barcode')
```

the line above saving the created bar code into the current directory, but i want to directly store this into s3 how can i achieve that?